# How to create a confirmation question in Linux?

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script

I have a certain command (`git push server-name`) that has major consequences. How to require confirmation for ***this command only***? It should ignore white space.

The confirmation could be `Enter 'yes i am sure.' to confirm:`

By the way, there is another command that does not require confirmation: `git push server-name-staging`.

Comment: You could wrap something around [that resembles the answers to SO's "*How do I prompt a user for confirmation in bash script?*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885525/how-do-i-prompt-a-user-for-confirmation-in-bash-script), combine it with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431775/993018)...(Not sure if you can *override* `push`, but you could create a new macro name and slightly alter your habbits.) *This is guesswork, I'm unsure if it's possible to pass arguments to these aliases.*

Comment: That's very helpful info. I thought since it is a bash script it belongs on Unix.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alias `git` to a script you're going to write:

```
$ alias git=mygit
```

...which lives in your `PATH` somewhere and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "push" ]
then
    /bin/echo -n "Enter 'yes i am sure.' to confirm: "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" != "yes i am sure." ]
    then
        echo So indecisive...
        exit 1
    fi
fi

git "$@"
```

Comment: use `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` -- the former will protect any argument that contains whitespace. In some shells, you can `read -p "Enter 'yes i am sure.' to confirm: " answer`

Comment: Yep, `$*` is a bad habit of mine. :) Fixed that. I'll keep the `read` command as-is for portability.

Comment: The outer conditional is not needed anymore with `"$@"`.

Comment: Thanks. Thinking about it more, it is not really necessary to use `alias git=mygit`. It might be better to use a separate command for   `git push`. A new command `push` that runs the above script: `if ["$1" = "server-name"] ...`. That's actually safer because then we don't need `git "$@"`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it in the question, but does this work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @BSeven: I can't see why not. It's about as portable as you could hope for. If it doesn't work somewhere, it would be due to lack of a shell supporting aliases, or maybe a system with a nonstandard `/bin/echo`. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Re: `echo`, if you run into a system that doesn't understand `echo -n`, there are alternatives: trailing `\c`, `printf`, etc.